# How to keep Wordpress from changing & into html (&amp;) in post titles

Tags: wordpress

I am using a custom post type to track contacts. So, the post title will be something like John & Jane Jackson.

When I save the post, the & in the post title changes to & amp;  (ie: John & amp; Jackson) - this would be fine if I were using the title on the frontend, but I am pulling this contact data outside of Wordpress and using it for print material. So, I want the & to stay as & and not be changed to the html version.

Anyone know how to force Wordpress to keep whatever text is entered into the title field without altering it to hmtl?

Answer (score 0):

Add your content in HTMl mode not in VISUAL mode, then every thing'll be fine.
See the snap shot below...[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not working. I need the title to not be changed to HTML, and this does not work for that. Also, Since I have removed the editor, it is not an option to choose HTML view as a long term solution.