# How to keep Wordpress from changing & into html (&amp;)

Tags: wordpress

I'm using Wordpress and I have the exact same issue as stated in this thread:

[How to keep Wordpress from changing & into html (&amp;) in post titles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451904/how-to-keep-wordpress-from-changing-into-html-amp-in-post-titles)

For some reason ampersands in both the title and body of my Wordpress posts are being automatically turned into "& amp;". Unfortunately there was no answer posted and I can't find a solution anywhere. When the post is published, the final output for all the &s is just "&", but I want to stop it from putting "& amps;" while in the Wordpress editor's code view. I didn't have this problem before - it just appeared randomly. Other people who use this same Wordpress for my site tell me that the issue doesn't happen for them, so I believe the problem might be mine alone - possibly an encoding issue? Does anyone know?

Here's an image to show what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEJnl.jpg

The "&"s I want to stay as "&"s on the page. Every time I try to type an "&" it gets turned into "&"s - this has never happened for me before.

Comment: Are you using the visual editor or the code editor?

Comment: Ive used both, i still get the same issue

Comment: Well in the code view, you will always see `&amp;` because it's *code*. But you shouldn't necessarily be seeing it in the visual editor. I'd check what plugins you have installed.

Comment: No, it appeared as just & in the code view previously. It suddenly just started appearing as & amp; one day. In the visual editor (and when i preview as Ive stated) it appears as just &. Do you mean plugins for my internet browser?

Answer (score 0):

The symbol `&` html name is `&amp;`. Or you can use `&#38;` this is the symbol's html number.

Comment: That seems to work for &s used in the title, however it doesnt work for those in the body. Also I was hoping that maybe there was a setting on my PC or on wordpress or something that I could set that would prevent me needing to type that at all, because this is a problem that happened recently...

Comment: Actually it seems to switch back to & amp; when switching views or saving... :\

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have anything wrong here. Lets just go over what you are seeing:

- In the visual part of the editor, you see `&` and it is output as `&`. *This is functioning correctly.*
- In the code part of the editor, you see `&amp;`and it is output as `&`. *This is also functioning correctly, as you are in the **code** editor, and `&amp;` is code for `&`.*
- In the title, you sometimes have to put `&amp;` for it to output `&`. *This does happen sometimes unfortunately, and there's not much you can do about it*

Basically, to recap, you don't really have anything wrong. You have to remember that you are dealing in a coders environment, and these things happen.

It's only a problem once WordPress starts outputing `&amp;` on the front end.

Comment: I am aware of the fact that the final publication has just "&" as i want it. However, my issue is that in the code view, &'s are being turned into "& amp;"s (yes, i know thats the code form of &) even though previously they would just show up as &s. I realize this doesn't matter because the final product still produces the desired result of "&", but when there is a discrepancy you still need to discover what is causing it, because it wasn't doing that previously. The fact that others using the same Wordpress editor on my site are not having this issue whatsoever is a concern for example.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is already 2020, try this code:

```
function fix_post_titles($data) {
    $data['post_title'] = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $data['post_title']);
    return $data;
}
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'fix_post_titles', 99, 1);
```

Comment: Can you give description why this could fix the Problem ? also please take a moment to improve your question with this guide [ask]